# Explicit conversion when using the sum function of Linq GroupBy (C#)

Tags: c#, linq

I need help with using Linq GroupBy and Sum. This part of the program I'm coding returns error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"**

```
        private IEnumerable<dynamic> histix;

        public void CreateADKTran()
        {
            histix = File.ReadLines(PATH_LNHISTIX)
                         .Skip(1)
                         .Where(line => line.Substring(157, 3) == "PKK" &&
                                        Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(141, 16)) != 0 &&
                                        line.Substring(80, 1) != "*" &&
                                        (line.Substring(58, 1) == "6" || line.Substring(58, 3) == "310"))
                         .Select(line => new
                         {
                             hist_acct_no = line.Substring(0, 10).ToString(),
                             hist_tran_date = DateTime.ParseExact(line.Substring(61, 8), "yyyyMMdd", provider),
                             hist_outstanding = Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(89, 13).ToString()),
                             hist_angsuran = (Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(102, 2)) + Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(154, 2))) >= 100 ?
                                                               (Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(141, 13) + 1)) : (Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(141, 13))),
                             hist_txn_code = line.Substring(58, 3).ToString(),
                             hist_txn_type = line.Substring(58, 1).ToString()
                         });

            var histixSum = histix.GroupBy(x => new { x.hist_acct_no, x.hist_tran_date, x.hist_txn_type })
                                            .Select(x => new {
                                                histAcctno = x.Key.hist_acct_no,
                                                histTranDate = x.Key.hist_tran_date,
                                                histTxnType = x.Key.hist_txn_type,
                                                histOS = x.Last().hist_outstanding,
                                                histAngsuran = x.Sum(x => x.hist_angsuran),
                                                histTxnCode = x.Last().hist_txn_code
                                            });
         }
```

I've manage to pinpoint the issue to the line

```
histAngsuran = x.Sum(x => x.hist_angsuran)
```

I've tried converting it to Int32 but the value exceeds the MaxValue.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: actually I cannot reproduce the casting error, but what I can reproduce is that you are not allowed to use the name `x` again: `histAngsuran = x.Sum(xDifferent => xDifferent.hist_angsuran)`

Comment: the message sounds like a compile error. Which actually does not make any sense because in the select statement it is clearly declared as decimal so the `Sum` method will return a `decimal`. Or did you get this at run time when the query is evaluated? I have the feeling that we are missing information here

Comment: @MongZhu I've edited the code in my question. This part of the code is actually the very beginning section of the program. I got the error when I ran it.

Comment: I don't know why people are suggesting to convert to `int` or `long`. This seems wrong since you'll truncate everything after the decimal point, i.e. you'll loose information.

Comment: Also I don't see how this error could show up in the line you think it is. I think there is some mistake in your analysis and the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I found the line out when I debug the code. The error message also shows when I tried to see the value oh `histixSum`. It works when I removed `histAngsuran = x.Sum(x => x.hist_angsuran)` so I figured that's the culprit.

Comment: I don't think this error can appear during runtime, only during compile time, i.e. you could not have been able to debug code with that error. But actually I'm not 100% sure about that anymore 

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I wish I could post a screenshot image here :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a wild guess but the problem might by that `histix` contains `dynamic` objects. It could be that the compiler is unable to select the correct overload of [`Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0) and defaults to the implementation for `int`. During runtime this then crashes with the error you posted because the `decimal hist_angsuran` (hidden behind `dynamic`) does not fit the implementation.

Try helping out the compiler by doing:

```cs
histAngsuran = x.Sum(x => (decimal)x.hist_angsuran),
```

Update:

Yup, I just verified it. You are getting a `RuntimeBinderException` without the cast to `(decimal)`:

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```cs
IEnumerable<dynamic> histix = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => new { hist_angsuran = (decimal)i });

var histixSum = histix.Sum(x => x.hist_angsuran);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to Int64.

Int32 has a max value of 2147483647; [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=net-6.0)

Int64 has a max value of 9223372036854775807. [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/int64-maxvalue-field-in-c-sharp-with-examples/)

Comment: I've tried converting it to Int64 but the only thing changed is the error now shows *Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'.*. I don't know how to set `histAngsuran` to Int64 as it is declared within the Lambda expression.